# Android AsyncTask wait until finished to retrieve data and display it in the ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this methods

```
private void changeContacts() {
        if (mOnlyDisplayContacts) {
                listContact = fetchContactResponse(mView);
            } else {
                // Other code
            }

        contactAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(context, listContact, this);

        mContactsList.setAdapter(mContactAdapter);

        mContactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

private List<Contact> fetchContactResponse(final String view) {


        AsyncContactSearch mLoadContactTask = new AsyncContactSearch(context, limit, offset, view, search);
        try {
            listContacts = mLoadContactTask.execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listContacts;
    }
```

Class Task

```
public class AsyncContactSearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<LinphoneContact>> {

    private Context context;
    private int limit, offset;
    private String view, search;

    public AsyncContactSearch(Context context, int limit, int offset, String view, String search) {
        this.context = context;
        this.limit = limit;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.view = view;
        this.search = search;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Contact> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String domain = SharedPreferencesManager.getDomain(context);
        String authToken = SharedPreferencesManager.getAuthtoken(context);
        final List<Contact> listContact = new ArrayList<>();

        RestAPI RestAPI = RetrofitHelper.create(RestAPI.class, domain);

        Call<ContactList> searchWithTerms =
                userRestAPI.searchWithTerms(authToken, "", limit, offset);
        searchWithTerms.enqueue(
                new Callback<ContactList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call, Response<ContactList> response) {
                        ContactList contactList = response.body();
                        if (contactList == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        List<Contact> contacts = contactList.getRows();
                        for (Contact c : contacts) {
                            listContact.add(
                                    ContactsManager.getInstance().addFromAPI(c));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ContactList> call, Throwable throwable) {}
                });

        Collections.sort(
                listContact,
                new Comparator() {

                    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                        String x1 = ((LinphoneContact) o1).getCompany();
                        String x2 = ((LinphoneContact) o2).getCompany();
                        int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

                        if (sComp != 0) {
                            return sComp;
                        }

                        String x3 = ((LinphoneContact) o1).getFirstName();
                        String x4 = ((LinphoneContact) o2).getFirstName();
                        return x3.compareTo(x4);
                    }
                });
        return listContact;
    }
}
```

The problem is (debugging the code) that while the search task is still running, the method is triggered immediately `contactAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(context, listContact, this);`listContact is empty,then the execution goes on assigns the Adapter to the ListView, while the recovery task goes on and inserts the elements into the List, on the screen the ListView remains empty

Answer (score 0):

You are using the retrofit for API call so no need to use `AsyncTask`. The retrofit will make the API call `asynchronously` and deliver the result in `callback onResponse()`. Just move your logic inside `callback onResponse()`.